# external styling does not render correctly, in react-native-render-html

Tags: html, react-native, react-native-render-html

I want to display HTML that got from API response like this

```json
{
    "title": "Testing Bootstrap styling",
    "preview": "Ini lagi testing bootstrap styling",
    "body":"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'><link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/klikcair/digitalcommunitylabs-system-notification-template/style.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi' crossorigin='anonymous'><title>DCB Notification - Ayo Aktivasi</title></head><body><div class='wrapper'><h1 class='title title-primary'>Ayo Aktivasi Sekarang</h1><div class='content'><p>Selamat bergabung. Ayo aktivasi sekarang untuk menikmati berbagai fitur andalan.</p><ul><li><b>Setor dan Transfer</b><p>Kirim dana antar rekening atau antar bank.</p></li><li><b>Cek mutasi</b><p>Telusuri transaksi dengan mudah.</p></li><li><b>Akunmu lebih aman</b><p>Datamu aman dan terenkripsi.</p></li></ul></div></div></body></html>",
    "bodyType": "HTML",
    "tags": [
        "Keanggotaan"
    ],
}
```

HTML rendered successfully but buggy for external styling. The external styling is not rendered properly.

[the result should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hGx1.png)

but on my device the result is like this:

[result on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHGTI.png)

[for source code:](https://snack.expo.dev/@toniebe/render-html)

external style can render correctly, like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mv8l.png)